# React Redux state.set not refreshing my components

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, immutability

I am using a immutable state in my reducer, initially i am dispatching 'REQUESTLOGINDATASUCCEEDED' event which calls state.set() it was refreshing my components, then i want to update the same state variable i dispatched "USERPREFERENCESUCCEEDED" and call the same state.set() my component is not refreshing now. PFB the code.

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
  loginData : {}
});

function DataGridContainerReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUESTLOGINDATASUCCEEDED':
        return state.set('loginData', action.loginData);
    case 'USERPREFERENCESUCCEEDED':
        return updateUserPreference(state, action.userPreference);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


function updateUserPreference(state, userPreference) {
    debugger;
    let loginData = state.get('loginData');
    let searchDataIndex = 0;
    loginData.userPreferences.splice(searchDataIndex, 1);
    loginData.userPreferences.push(userPreference);
    return state.set('loginData', loginData);
}

export default DataGridContainerReducer;
```

Please check and let me know what is the issue here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you dispatching USERPREFERENCESUCCEEDED?

Comment: @whs.bsmith I called a action function in saga. action function will be dispatching "USERPREFERENCESUCCEEDED", "yield put(userPreferenceSucceeded(userPreference));" in saga, "export function userPreferenceSucceeded(userPreference) {
  return {
    type: USERPREFERENCESUCCEEDED,
    userPreference
  }
} 
" from actions

Comment: Did you check if the state does mutate? Also, you must `dispatch(actionCreator())`.

Comment: @medik yes, state is updating. i checked this in redux dev tool.

Comment: Try using an object for userPreferences instead, I think React doesn't like trying to detect changes in array indexes.

Comment: Immutable docs say: `push (...) return a new immutable collection`. Looks like you're not mutating the data properly. Try to `return state.set('loginData', loginData).set('anyName', Math.random());` and see what happens.

Comment: @medik it was working now, so what is the solution here?

Comment: `return state.set('loginData', loginData.userPreferences.splice(searchDataIndex, 1).push(userPreference));`. Your solution is setting unmodified `loginData`, because `splice` and `push` return a new object without mutating the `self`. You are not changing the store, that's why it's not updating.